# MouseOver and Speak

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, scheduling, sound

I am having an issue where `Mouseover` doesn't work with `Speak` and instead returns `Null`. All of the examples below have failed. I am looking for an example that works with `MouseOver` and not with `EventHandler`.

```
With[{s := Speak["warning"]}, Mouseover["text", s]]

DynamicModule[{s = Speak["warning"]}, Mouseover["text", s]] 

With[{s := Speak["warning"]}, 
 Dynamic@If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], s, "Hello World"]]
```

This following works ok, but is not what I am looking for.

```
EventHandler["Text", {"MouseClicked" :> Speak["warning"]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Both of those work:

```
EventHandler["Text", "MouseEntered" :> Speak["Kuba"]]

Button["Text", Speak["Kuba"], AutoAction -> True, Appearance -> None]
```

You get Null because it is what Speak evaluates to, iyou would need to follow it with `; "Text"` to see it. `Mouseover` won't work because it will not hold its arguments and even if you put `Dynamic` around the second argument it will probably be cached and run once. So either of those two solutions above or the one proposed by kglr will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CurrentValue["MouseOver"]`:

```
With[{s := Speak["warning"]}, 
 Dynamic @ If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], s, "text"]]
```